# POST request to a REST server

Tags: java, rest

So, I'm trying to create a simple (and I mean simple) POST request. Here is the class on the server-side.

```
@Stateless
@Path("cards")
public class CardsFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Cards> {

    @POST
    @Path("test")
    @Consumes({"text/plain"})
    public void createTestCard() {
        Cards card = new Cards();
        card.setName("Test Card");

        super.create(card);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("count")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String countREST() {
        return String.valueOf(super.count());
    }
}
```

The GET method works just fine, but the POST method isn't working for me. I'm using Chrome's Advanced Rest Client.

- The URL is http://localhost:8080/dc-rest/webresources/cards/test
- The type is POST
- My header is like so: Content-Type: text/plain

And that's it.

I keep getting a "400: Bad Request. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

When I open the response in the JSON window, all it says is "Unexpected token <"

Here are the request headers if that makes any difference.

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
Content-Type: text/plain
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=f4c746a32b46244d422800192f04; treeForm_tree-    hi=treeForm:tree:applications

Body is empty.
```

And the response:

```
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7) 
Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE 
Allow: GET,DELETE,OPTIONS,PUT,POST 
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type 
Content-Language:  
Content-Type: text/html Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2016 20:48:12 GMT 
Connection: close Content-Length: 1105

Body:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  - Error report</title><style type="text/css"><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request</h1><hr/><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b>Bad Request</p><p><b>description</b>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</p><hr/><h3>GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0 </h3></body></html>
```

Comment: Can you post the request and response data from the client you are using?  The entire thing.  url, verbs, request and response bodies, headers, the works.

Comment: Bit messy but I think it's all there.

Comment: Man, this API does not seem to help you figure out why you are getting the error does it.  I can tell you that the "Unexpected token <" error you are getting is because the Json serializer is expecting JSON and it is getting HTML (xml) back.  It is throwing that exception because it sees the starting character in the response that you are returning as "<" instead of "{" or "[".  Now im not sure why it is returning a 400.  You might try the following: make sure content-length is set, make sure accept and content-type are set to application/json (I assume the server speaks in JSON)

Answer (score 2):

The 400-Bad request response is likely because the server has expressed that it expects a specific content type

```
@Consumes({"text/plain"}
```

However the client is not indicating that the post body is of this type.

To solve this, make sure that the POST request from your client contains the following HTTP header:

> Content-Type: text/plain

Or, perhaps it is the case that you are not POSTing plain text and you intend to POST XML or JSON.  Whatever the intended type, you just need to make sure the client and server are in agreement about it.

Comment: Both the @Consumes and the Content-Type say text/plain. There's nothing in the body at all. Maybe it's a problem that nothing's in the body?

Comment: Possibly.  It is generally considered bad form to POST without a body.  In fact, I have seen network firewalls rules that block requests of this type as a potential security issue.

Comment: Another interpretation of the error is that the client is claiming the payload contains text, yet there is no text in the payload.  Sounds like a bad request to me..... So my suggestion for something else to try, just to get this to work, would be to remove the @Consumes annotation (which is optional) and to omit the content-type header in the request (also optional).

Comment: Although long-term, you should probably re-think your API.  The REST convention for POST is to create a resource by passing a representation of that resource to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If an HTTP request has a body, it must have either Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header.

With neither, the request has no body -- not even a body of length 0. If you want to send an empty body, the request should have header `Content-Length: 0`.

There is a semantic difference between having no body and having an empty body. The server apparently rejects the POST request with no body. (Though the request is actually *syntactically* valid according to RFC)

---

Actually, this part is not quite clear ([discussion thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2012OctDec/thread.html#msg414) (don't read)). And some implementations set `Content-Length: 0` for `GET` requests; some implementations omit `Content-Length: 0` for empty POST bodies; both are wrong... Sometimes they work sometimes they don't. Welcome to the chaotic world of HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

I hate it when this happens. It was something else entirely, my persistence bean is messed up. When I commented out "super.create(card)" in my POST method, everything worked (request body or no).

Still have no idea why that resulted in "400: Bad Request. The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Seems like I have another problem to figure out, but this one at least is solved.

Thank y'all for helping!